# Refactoring code in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, class, static, refactoring, windows-forms-designer

I have a windows form application that I am attempting to refactor - I have some functions and variables that I want to separate into other classes. When I do that, I cannot access the members of the `MainClass`, like the controls of the Windows Form. I could make them public static, but then I have issues with the designer. Example, in a `NewClass` function I refactored, I would reference a control like:

```
MainClass.listBox1.Items.Clear();
```

But this wont work as the control is private. This gives the errors:

```
1. An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MainClass.listBox1'
2 'MainClass.listBox1' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

So, if I make `listBox1` public static so my `NewClass` can access it, I get the following error everywhere `this.listBox1` appears in the Designer.cs:

```
1 Member 'MainClass.listBox1' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead
```

So my first thought is to change the this.listBox1 to MainClass.listBox1, but I think of the warning at the top of the Designer.cs page:

```
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
```

Obviously these arent my real code samples/names, but the errors are what I'm getting and I've replaced the names with appropriate names for the sake of generalization. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I've seen this too; in trying to set a `MainWindow`s text box for example, I can't access it, and making it public sometimes works and sometimes doesn't (to do this I would have to edit the auto-generated file). A potential solution would be a `MainWindow.ClearListBox1()` method that (inside) `MainWindow` could clear the list box

Comment: This is not about refactoring at all, but about elementary object oriented principles. Making things static and public is not a good practice and is essentially procedural programming. In fact you are making things worse.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I wasn't suggesting that making the controls public or static is the right course of action, merely that access because of protection level is the error given so naturally those are the first two things that come to mind. I suppose it's worth nothing that I'm just a novice at OOP; my goal here is to learn from my mistakes and issues. Thanks!

Comment: At least with the feedback I gave you, you know you are on the wrong track.  Don't make things static.

Answer (score 0):

The refactoring you are trying to do breaks many of the common conventions we follow today.  Ex: MVC or MVVM.

The point is that we try not to update UI code from other locations.  Encapsulate your code so that you do not need to force dependencies between the view and the controller.

In your example, there should be some starting point in your application.

```
MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
Application.Run(mainClass);
```

In your main class constructor, you may have the equivalent of a controller:

```
public MainClass(){
     myController = new MyController();
     RefreshControls();
}
```

So using this function, your list box can have a data source that lives in the controller:

```
public void RefreshControls()
{
    listbox1.DataSource = myController.Students;
    //Clear data from UI, add data to UI, do other stuff
}
```

Now from here, you can go a number of different ways.  One thing is you can do is use events to refresh application data from the UI if you have a RefreshData method on your controller:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myController.RefreshData();
        //RefreshControls();  Wouldn't need to do, see below
    }
```

You can have events that listen to changes in the data (two-way binding available in WPF highly recommended):

```
    private void myController_DataChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshControls();
    }
```

Note that it is NOT recommended that you mess with the designer.  It can be extremely touchy, especially as your application grows.  I would recommended moving any controls you want to manually change into the .cs class and manage the control there.  That is something for advanced users and your changes would likely get overwritten next time you open the designer anyway.